# Difference between website's access and web service's acess

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679317/c-library-impersonate-problem), I've met another problem where the request just doesn't go through. When I was first given the task, the website was working like so :

Website -> Web Services -> Library -> External Server (TextML Server for those who might be familiar with it).

I was asked a couple of things and of them was to get the web service layer out of the way to improve performance, like this :

Website -> Library -> External Server

So I went through the code and made the proper changes but I faced a problem where authentication was a problem, I asked the question and found the solution. Now the Website use the correct user to connect with the External Server. But then the method connecting with this particular server just run and goes on, and on, and on.... forever.

So the question is quite simple :

**Is there a difference for the External Server either its a Web Service or a website that's is trying to establish a connection?**

I use c#, asp on Windows XP and when I debut I use the local IIS which runs IIS 5.0 (I know its kinda old)

Also, one point to note if that if inside the same method, I use the webservice from my website to connect, it works and then the next line of code I use the library, it doesn't.

Example code :

```
WsDocServerService.DocServer doc = new WsDocServerService.DocServer();
XmlDocument oIndexList = new XmlDocument();
oIndexList = doc.GetSystemDocument(INDEX_FILE);//This will work
oIndexList = DocServerController.GetSystemDocument(INDEX_FILE);//This wont
//But both way I use the DocServerController.GetSystemDocument(filename); to get the file
```

Thanks a lot!
Although, I don't need a solution, maybe a proper answer could help me to solve the problem!
**EDIT**

The web service method called above is calling the controller method :

```
DocServerController.GetSystemDocument(INDEX_FILE);
```

That's why I thought this was useless to go with the Web Service, and yes I meant an .ASMX web Service.

I went with the admin of the server and reviewed the event log, there is an error relating a COM+ program that appears every time I run the above method. Sadly, I think the problem has something to do with the server itself.

Do you think I should shut the question?

**EDIT**

Event viewer logged entry :

```
The run-time environment has detected an inconsistency in its internal state.
This indicates a potential instability in the process that could be caused by
the custom components running in the COM+ application, the components they 
make use of, or other factors. VariantUnmarshal: CoUnmarshalInterface for 
IID_IDispatch failure

Server Application ID: {F27C90B8-C40E-4B76-8F01-A8C035EACC08}
Server Application Instance ID:
{79C9FDFC-78AD-461B-95E6-80FF54880317}
Server Application Name: Textml Server
Error Code = 0x800706ba : The RPC server is unavailable.
COM+ Services Internals Information:
File: d:\nt\com\complus\src\comsvcs\ucp\assoc.cpp, Line: 723
Comsvcs.dll file version: ENU 2001.12.4720.3959 shp

For more information, see Help and Support Center at  
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: Hint#1: you don't need `new XmlDocument()` since you're going to immediately overwrite it with a new document.

Comment: Also, this is going to turn out to be specific to the TextML server. It will also be specific to the way you had the web site and web service set up. There is no generic difference between a web site and a web service. Also, I presume you mean an ASMX web service?

Comment: That's going to be pretty much impossible to answer without knowing what the web service does under the hood...

Comment: @David: post the error from the event log.

Comment: Nevermind, it'll go to Monday, sorry!

Comment: It's so strange. I can't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some COM+ misconfiguration on your server.

Here are some workarounds by other people running into this problem (Event 4689):
http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=4689&eventno=3980&source=COM+&phase=1

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at these solutions and I'm currently trying some of these! I hope it'll work! Thanks!

Comment: None of the solution provided worked. I'll stay with the old pattern. :(

Comment: Is reinstalling the server (not likely) an option?

Comment: It is being used in production, unfortunately, reinstalling isn't an option. Anyway this TextMl Server is broken. I'll mark as the good answer as it will probably lead me to the solution! There are just some manipulations I can't do by myself. Thanks oles